# Glitchy-looking transparent alpha channel PNG when imported as "Image as Plane" in Cycles

Tags: import, image, transparency

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/12/13/tutorial-first-lowpoly-tropical-island/), and when I import the reference image I get a glitchy plane:

[image]

(the one on the right is the *Image as Plane*, while the one on the left is an *Empty* with an image)

I have made sure that the image, found online, was transparent, using Photoshop:

[image]

In trying to troubleshoot this, I have looked at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/importing-png-series-with-import-image-as-plane-is-blurred-and-has-artefacts), but it doesn't help me, as I can't reproduce the steps given in the answer.

Basically, I'm stuck looking for parameters for this object. There's nothing in the *Object Data* panel, I tweaked *Viewport Alpha* in the *Material* tab but still nothing...

Comment: can you upload the image in question?

Comment: The question was solved, but just to answer your comment, it's the same image that the user who made the tutorial uses - one of the first results for the "palm tree" image search on Google: http://pngimg.com/upload/palm_tree_PNG2489.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click ***import images as planes*** and the file browser opens, in the lower right, under 'import images as planes', you need to check the  **use alpha** checkbox, or you will get bizarre alpha junk.  Why this isn't a default I have no idea.

[image]

As an alternative on the UV/image editor press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the options window and enable "Use Alpha" 
[image]

Comment: Good to know, thanks! The answer of the question this is a duplicate of was really good as well.

Comment: @photox blender does not flag or attempts to destroy anything... simply enabling alpha (when importing images as planes or on the UV/image editor) will fix transparency. http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHkyR.gif   The image in question has RGB information on top of the Alpha. It's just a matter enabling so that blender uses it.  For a detailed explanation on the issue read the comments on this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/removing-alpha-from-png-image-with-set-alpha-node-gives-pixelated-result/21086#21086 no need to delete anything of reopen or use external software

Comment: Ok, that works, open the properties panel in the uv editor and check 'use alpha' can be used after importing without alpha enabled.