# Why is my PNG texture messed up after I import it?

Tags: image

[image: original image]
[image: imported image]

I made a leaf texture in photoshop and exported it as png and I hope to use it in a tree model I'm making in blender. However after I import it using the add-on "Import Images as Planes", this is the result. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635 and the comments at the end of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/removing-alpha-from-png-image-with-set-alpha-node-gives-pixelated-result/21086#21086 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104642/partly-ignored-png-alpha/104658#104658

Answer (score 1):

Found out the reason was because when selecting the image there is an import options box on the bottom-left corner of the window which contains an option labeled "Use Alpha" which must be checked in order for the image to be imported properly. 
[image: importing png as plane]

Answer (score 0):

Try Blender 2.79. I see no problem here. But be sure to make the background of the leaf transparent in Photoshop. No white layer beneath.